# No ServletContext set error while Autowiring AuthenticationManager in WsConfigurerAdapter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-ws

I have spring boot application which is using 'spring-boot-starter-security', 'spring-ws-security', 'spring-boot-starter-web-services'
I am facing below error while autowiring AuthenticationManager .

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'resourceHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No ServletContext set
```

I am trying to upgrade my spring boot application from 1.4.6 to 2.3.9.
My pom dependencies are

```
    <name>
       testproject</name>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-integration</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
    </properties>
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ws-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.wss</groupId>
            <artifactId>xws-security</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.crypto</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xmldsig</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>wsdl4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wsdl4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>15.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <version>1.4.199</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb.flyway-test-extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>6.3.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
       
        

    </dependencies>
```

My WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

```
class AuthenticationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

        @Autowired
        DatabaseUserDetailsService databaseUserDetailsService;

        @Bean
        public DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider() {
            DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
            provider.setUserDetailsService(databaseUserDetailsService);
            provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
            return provider;
        }
        @Bean
        @Override
        public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
            return super.authenticationManagerBean();
        }
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());

        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and().httpBasic().disable()
                    .csrf().disable();
        }
    }
```

My WsConfigurerAdapter

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
//@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableRetry
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    // Default to proper production url if not set.
    @Value("${wsdl.address.prefix}")
    private String wsdlAddressPrefix = <url>;

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(false);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "<path>");
    }

    @Bean(name = "stampedWorkingTimeEvents")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema stampedWorkingTimeEventsSchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName(<port>);
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri(<uri>);
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace(<namespace>);
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(stampedWorkingTimeEventsSchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema stampedWorkingTimeEventsSchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource(<xsd>));
    }

    @Bean
    XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor() {
        XwsSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor = new XwsSecurityInterceptor();
        securityInterceptor.setCallbackHandler(plainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler());
        securityInterceptor.setPolicyConfiguration(new ClassPathResource("securityPolicy.xml"));
        return securityInterceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler plainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler() {
        SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler callbackHandler = new SpringPlainTextPasswordValidationCallbackHandler();
        callbackHandler.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        return callbackHandler;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(securityInterceptor());
    }
  

}
```

I have also tried excluding WebMvcAutoConfiguration,

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration
```

but it again gives me below error on other functionality since it is dependent on this

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException
```